# integrate jqmPhp with symfony2

Tags: symfony

I try to integrate jqmphp with symfony2.

I have copied the lib folder into `/vendor/jqmphp` and update the autoloader file but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, ensure that you followed these steps carefully.

1. Copy lib into `/vendor/jqmphp`
2. In `autoload.php` add to the bottom:

   ```
   require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/jqmphp/lib/jqmPhp.php';
   ```
3. In your Controller you can start using `\JqmPhp()`

Comment: thank you for your reply ,i got a new error message : jqmPage' not found , how can include all the files in the lib directory ?

Comment: Actually, all that files should be automatically included, because `jqmPhp` class already contains all that `includes`

Comment: Probably you should check constant `define('JQMPHP_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../'.JQMPHP_FOLDER.'/').'/', true);` in `JqmPhp` class

Comment: i got the error message in this line of code  $p = new jqmPage('example-4');

Comment: Than you should debug it... It has nothing to deal with Symfony2 anymore ;)

Comment: One last tip - you should call that method from your main object, like:
`$jqmphp = new jqmPhp(); $jqmphp->addBasicPage($arg1, $arg2);`